# Cannot login via SSH after installing LAMP via Tasksel

Tags: ssh, lamp, tasksel

After install LAMP via Tasksel I cannot log in anymore via SSH: `connection refused`. I'm sure that install LAMP this way causes this problem. I had this once before.

I'm still connected via SSH, so I'm able to fix it now. How can I fix SSH?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, maybe I was a bit to fast with posting a question. But I was in panic ;)
Installing openSSH via Tasksel fixed my problem.

Filled in [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1099200) on Launchpad

Comment: **Please clarify.** Was OpenSSH-server not already installed, or had *Tasksel* removed it, or something else?

Comment: openSSH was installed before installing LAMP. I made a bug rapport on launchpad.

Comment: Add link, to LaunchPad (bug report).

Comment: Tasksel is still a dangerous beast - **never** use it to uninstall something - it will remove every package it would have installed for that task!

Comment: @david6 done it.